# Shell script to detect PDFs with non-ASCII contents

Tags: shell-script, pdf, ascii

I need a shell script to detect valid PDFs. That is, I need to retain only plain ASCII PDFs. Other PDFs which contain non-ASCII contents and malicious scripts need to be deleted. How could I go about doing that? Is there any script available to do it?

Comment: Clarifying question: if the PDF contains only pictures of puppies, do you want to count it as ASCII or not?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, at a high level? A computer can't detect ‘malicious’ scripts. Malice is in intent, and computers can't parse human intent. E.g. deleting a file: did you mean to do it, or was it malicious? Ifa computer could tell what you meant, we'd be using it through mind control. ;)

Comment: Did you look at this [zeltser](http://zeltser.com/reverse-malware/analyzing-malicious-documents.html)?

Comment: You mean 'text' or really ASCII? An ü or è would be OK?

Comment: people upload the pdf's via web interface all the uploaded pdf's stored in the directory at some instance some script or malicious files upload via web just rename to .pdf extension.in that case its harmful for server so i need to script which scan the file type of uploaded  whether its have valid content or not

Comment: @user512213: Does `man 1 file` help?

Comment: @matteo i want retained only pdf's having Text with pictures.other then anything needs to be discarded.

Comment: That a PDF has only text code points that fall in the ASCII range is completely unrelated to whether it has malicious content. A malicious script could be in ASCII, and there is nothing harmful about characters not in ASCII.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is called a virus scanner. Eg. [ClamAV](http://clamav.net/)

Comment: virus scanner scan  and remove only known malicious scripts how to remove unknown scripts.is it virus scanner do this operation.

Comment: How will you differentiate between good or bad? You too will only scan for known attack vectors. Although very broad, in fact you described one of those vectors above 'non-ASCII contents'.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few python scripts here. "The Malware Archives: PDF Files" also Bruce Schneier has mentioned this on his site.

pdf2ps is easy but much less sure. This is interesting  PDF/A http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A disallows multimedia elements.